# $k[x]/(x^n) \otimes_{k[x]} k[y]/(y^m)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

This is part of an exercise from Eisenbud:

$k$ is a field, describe as explicitly as possible

a) $k[x]/(x^n) \otimes_{k[x]} k[y]/(y^m)$

b) $k[x] \otimes_{k} k[y]$

Any hint ?

Comment: Well start by changing the name of the variable in one side from $x$ to $y$ so it becomes $k[x]\otimes k[y]$

Comment: @WLOG, what are you tensoring over? $k[x]$or $k$?

Comment: @user114539: I have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a)$ you can use the fact that $R/I\otimes_R R/J\cong R/(I+J)$, so it is $k[x]/((x^n)+(x^m))$. What does that become if $n\mid m$? I believe that the second one has been asked on this website, $k[x]\otimes_k k[y]\cong k[x,y]$. I know this is not an answer yet, if you need further help, let me know and i will write more.

Later: You can find it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158445/kx-otimes-k-kx-cong-kx-y)

Comment: can you link me the answer to point b ) ?

Comment: $n | m$ is not required, for what you are trying to imply $n \le m$ suffices